# How can I execute functions in cPanel using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, cron, cpanel

So, I've been trying to execute the function Cron::add_line using an script that I have builded and it didn't work properly yet. The script login into cPanel but in the second part it don't execute the json-api to execute the function add_line, I've did many searches about this but never found anything to make me comprehend how it works in cURL.

If I type the command url in my browser, it works and create the cron, otherwise, using my script it doesn't work.

If anyone could help I appreciate!

Thanks!

Code:

```
<?php
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$site = 'https://' . $_REQUEST['site'] . ':2083';
$auth_url = $site . '/login/?';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $auth_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user=' . $username . '&pass=' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100020);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$h = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($result == true && strpos($h['url'], "cpsess"))
{
    $pattern = "/.*?(\/cpsess.*?)\/.*?/is";
    $preg_res = preg_match($pattern, $h['url'], $cpsess);
}

$cpcmd_url = $site . "$ENV{'" . $cpsess[1] . "'}" . '/json-api/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cpcmd_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'cpanel?user=$username&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Cron&cpanel_jsonapi_func=add_line&cpanel_jsonapi_version=2&command=GET http://www.cdihost.com.br/admin/cron.php&day=*&hour=*&minute=*/5&month=*&weekday=*');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100020);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some debugging, like `error_log($cpcmd_url);` to see if the url is correct. Also, in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, **cpanel?** seems wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks! I did this and found the error! Now, it works perfect! :)